# Unable to create rawdisk in Virtualbox on Mint 21

Tags: usb, virtualbox, bootable

*Disclaimer: I don't yet have much experience with Linux.*

**Host OS:** Mint 21 (based on Ubuntu 22.04)

I'm unable to create a rawdisk via terminal ([guide found here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/)), which is necessary for Virtualbox (v.7) to recognize a bootable USB stick which houses the install files for my guest OS (Win7). Here's the command (from [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/) and other sources ([etc](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/virtualbox-virtual-machine-boot-usb.html#For_Linux_Ubuntu_1904_VirtualBox_Virtual_Machine_USB_boot)))

```
sudo vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/usb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb
```

Here's the error I receive:

```
VBoxManage: error: Error code VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER at /home/vbox/tinderbox/build-trunk/svn/src/VBox/Storage/VMDK.cpp(4481) in function int vmdkRawDescParseConfig(PVMDKIMAGE, char**, uint32_t*, uint32_t*, void**, size_t*, bool*, char**)
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: could get raw descriptor for '/home/user1/usb.vmdk'
VBoxManage: error: Error code VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER at /home/vbox/tinderbox/build-trunk/svn/src/VBox/Storage/VMDK.cpp(5296) in function int vmdkCreateImage(PVMDKIMAGE, uint64_t, unsigned int, const char*, PCVDGEOMETRY, PCVDGEOMETRY, PCRTUUID, PVDINTERFACEPROGRESS, unsigned int, unsigned int)
VBoxManage: error: Cannot create the raw disk VMDK: VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER
VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

Running the command without `sudo` yields the same outcome. I've also added my user to the `disk` group. Here is the output from `sudo fdisk -l` which is where I'm trying to map the rawdisk to:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 59.38 GiB, 63753420800 bytes, 124518400 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0 FD      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

I'm presently stuck, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the fault of Vbox v7 (getting very same behavior on archlinux since update). v6 worked perfectly, v7 neither can boot from vmdks, previously(v6) created from real drives, not create them.